# Magento2 backend keeps logging me out after ~10 minutes of inactivity

Tags: magento2

Literally the title.

I've set Cookie TTL to 7200 seconds, which are 2 hours.

Hoever, Magento2 keeps logging me out from the backend after a *few* minutes of idleing.

How can I prevent premature logging out? Am using 2.1.5!

Comment: You can set the logout time in admin settings, go to the `admin > Stores > Configuration > Advanced Tab > Admin > Admin Session Lifetime (seconds)` change the log out value.

Answer (score 1):

**To increase session to time for Admin , you need to go :**

**Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Admin -> Security ->** Admin Session Lifetime (**it must be in seconds**).

**Uncheckd** use System value option and add your value in textbox.

Minimumm second is **60** and Maximum is **31536000 (for one year).**

**Refer below screenshot for more details.**

[image]

Comment: As written in the question itself the value here is 7200 seconds, which are two hours. Increasing this number will not change anything as I still get logged out after several minutes.

Comment: After changing the settings have you cleared the cache ?

Comment: Sure thing, I delete cache for literally everything in M2

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's caused by PHP's `session.gc_maxlifetime` setting. Magento makes use of PHP's native sessions, at least in some capacity. The default value is 1440 (24mins).

Comment: This did the trick. The maxlifetime can be changed in `php.ini` location of which varies depending on how PHP is installed and what sort it is ( CGI Vs. FPM etc)